# Is there any tool to create Jenkins Plugin?

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that is working fine. Now i need to create the Jenkins Plugin bundling the whole functionality of the current Jenkins job.

I know we can create Jenkins job using maven, jelly and java. But I want some easy way of creating the plugin.

Do anyone know any tools that does my requirement.?????

Comment: should a "wiki" entry.. than a question.. (it may get closed in the current form)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you already known, in most cases, we develop jenkins plugin using maven & java.

But as an alternative, you can always choose other methods if you you like and here are some:

If you are not good at Java and would like to try develop jenkins plugin in Ruby or Python , you can try:

1. https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins.py/wiki
   https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins.py/wiki/Getting-Started-With-Python-Plugins
2. [Jenkins Plugin development in Ruby](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+plugin+development+in+Ruby)

If you don't like Maven and want to try other build tool like Gradle, then this is for you:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+JPI+Plugin

Also, I found in CloudBee site there is a way to develop jenkins plugin using only Groovy script,this is super easy and I am sure you will like it.
https://www.cloudbees.com/event/topic/groovy-way-write-jenkins-plugin